# How to pass user id in javascript or in ajax to fetch record from database if using laravel framework?

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, laravel, laravel-4

I have fetched task title from database. Now I want if I click on task title it should show description of that particular task on the same page using toggle.

I have tried AJAX and JavaScript but found no result. Can anyone help by providing a small example related to this topic?

```
<button type="button" id="button" value="submit" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="javascript:fload($usermm->id);">{{ $usermm->TaskTitle }}</button>
```

Comment: Make it work without JavaScript first, _then_ add fancy page transitions. Not every one is on a super-fast connection.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<button type="button" id="button" value="submit" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="javascript:fload({{{ $usermm->id }}});">{{{ $usermm->TaskTitle }}}</button>
```

Use `{{{ $usermm->TaskTitle }}}` (3 curly brackets instead of 2) to make sure you escape the data in the view.

**UPDATE**
I'm not going to write all code for you but I can give you a clue:

```
function fload(id)
{
    [...]
    var url='mytaskurl?id=' +id;
    [...]
}
```

**UPDATE #2**
Here is an example of using Ajax with Laravel:
http://blog.igeek.info/2013/using-ajax-in-laravel/

Comment: what to call in java script.I am new to java script

Comment: Tell where to pass id in ajax.

Comment: Thanks,I will try my best to implement it

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi If you’re new to JavaScript, learn the basics first before trying to dive straight in with AJAX page transitions.

Comment: here you are: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: Not able to implement

Comment: @violator667 still it is not working .Please refer me any link where I can see such examples related to jquery ajax

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi I edited my answer with a link to a small tutorial